# How to Include CSS for Home Page only in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I want to load **css** file only in home page alone.

I have tried with this way,but it loads on every page.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Banners::css/banners.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Please let me know how to add condition in layout xml file like we do on old magento layout file

```
 <catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>
        </reference>
 </catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got to `app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout` and create

**cms_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Namespace_ModuleName::css/banners.css"/>

    </head> 
 </page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create layout file to **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml** with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Namespace_ModuleName::css/banners.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create CSS file into below directory.

```
app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/css/web/circle.css
```

Create the Layout file into below directory.

```
app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml
```

Add below code in cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="Namespace_ModuleName::css/circle.css" />
  </head>
</page>
```